# can I increase the power going into my laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery

I have a gaming laptop (acer aspire timelineX). I'm having trouble when I play any graphically intense games(guildwars 2). I set the settings all the way to low and after a short while I will get the warning sound that the battery cable is unplugged and the screen will dim to low for a few seconds, this will continue on and off for a few minutes and eventually subside. After playing for a while the performance will start to drop.

I'm guessing the machine isn't getting enough power, is there a way to feed it more or is there another problem/solution going on here?

Comment: If you're still under warranty then call Acer, they might replace the power supply if it's faulty. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Check the power supply with a voltmeter or have it tested at a local shop.  AS noted by @Sammitch there is not much else you can do.

Comment: If this happens while its plugged into the wall, supplying more voltage to the laptop, will only damage the laptop.  **Something is defective with your hardware.**

Comment: @Ramhound This is only the case if there isn't something wrong with the AC adapter.

Answer (score 0):

As @sammitch and @Dave M suggested, I would first get the power adapter checked out, because if it is a low voltage problem, that's the likely culprit. Replacements only cost $20, anyway, so the risk of wasting $$ is low.

If that doesn't solve the issue, you may want to take a look at the motherboard, starting with the connector for the adapter (make sure solder isn't broken). Then check for any bulging or broken capacitors anywhere on the board. If there's any problems with the board, it's up to you to decide if the repairs are worth it. Laptops are so cheap nowadays and extensive repairs like bad caps aren't worth it.

Since this is a laptop, I'm assuming the GPU is onboard and not an expansion card, so there really isn't much physical inspection to do there. Make sure you have the latest drivers, but unless this an adapter that you can physically replace, the issue is likely with the motherboard or onboard GPU hardware.